Calculate Rolling sum in a data frame on a column based on leading n values as specified in another column
I am trying to calculate the rolling sum of the values in column 'a' for n leading values as specified in column b so that i get the answer as specified in column c

I tried to use slide_sum but when i pass the value of the argument 'after' as the column b, it throws an error.
d %>% mutate(c = slide_sum(a, after = b))
Error:
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `c = slide_sum(a, after = b)`.
Caused by error:
! `after` must have size 1, not 10.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.


Here is an option with purrr instead of slider:
df %>%
 mutate(c = map2_int(.x = seq_along(a), 
                     .y = b,
                     ~ sum(a[.x:(.x + .y - 1)], na.rm = TRUE)))

       a     b     c
   <int> <dbl> <int>
 1     1     2     3
 2     2     2     5
 3     3     2     7
 4     4     3    15
 5     5     1     5
 6     6     2    13
 7     7     2    15
 8     8     2    17
 9     9     3    19
10    10     1    10


in base R:
i <- sequence(df$b)
j <- cumsum(i == 1)
transform(df, c = tapply(a[i + j - 1], j, sum, na.rm =TRUE))

    a b  c
1   1 2  3
2   2 2  5
3   3 2  7
4   4 3 15
5   5 1  5
6   6 2 13
7   7 2 15
8   8 2 17
9   9 3 19
10 10 1 10


rollapply supports vector widths.  The first argument is the data, the second is the widths, the third is the function to apply, align="left" indicates we want to sum forward and partial=TRUE means that if the width extends past the end of the data then use whatever is available rather than that width.
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

d %>%
   mutate(c = rollapply(a, b, sum, align = "left", partial = TRUE))

giving
    a b  c
1   1 2  3
2   2 2  5
3   3 2  7
4   4 3 15
5   5 1  5
6   6 2 13
7   7 2 15
8   8 2 17
9   9 3 19
10 10 1 10

Note
Input in reproducible form:
d <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = rep(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), 2))


Perfect. Thanks. This has solved the issue

Vectorized in base R:
d <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = rep(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), 2))

transform(d, c = {i <- seq_along(a)
cs <- c(0, cumsum(a))
cs[pmin(i + b, length(cs))] - cs[i]})
#>     a b  c
#> 1   1 2  3
#> 2   2 2  5
#> 3   3 2  7
#> 4   4 3 15
#> 5   5 1  5
#> 6   6 2 13
#> 7   7 2 15
#> 8   8 2 17
#> 9   9 3 19
#> 10 10 1 10


Benchmarking
Candidate functions:
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

ftmfmnk <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    mutate(c = map2_int(.x = seq_along(a), 
                        .y = b,
                        ~ sum(a[.x:(.x + .y - 1)], na.rm = TRUE)))
}

fGrothendieck <- function(d) {
  d %>%
    mutate(c = rollapply(a, b, sum, align = "left", partial = TRUE))
}

fOnyambu <- function(df) {
  i <- sequence(df$b)
  j <- cumsum(i == 1)
  transform(df, c = tapply(a[i + j - 1], j, sum, na.rm =TRUE))
}

fjblood <- function(d) {
  transform(d, c = {i <- seq_along(a)
  cs <- c(0, cumsum(a))
  cs[pmin(i + b, length(cs))] - cs[i]})
}

Benchmarking dataset:
d <- data.frame(a = sample(100, 1e4, 1), b = sample(100, 1e4, 1))

Timings:
bench::mark(
  ftmfmnk = ftmfmnk(d),
  fGrothendieck = fGrothendieck(d),
  fOnyambu = fOnyambu(d),
  fjblood = fjblood(d),
  check = FALSE
)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 ftmfmnk         28.7ms   42.2ms     23.1     5.59MB    19.2 
#> 2 fGrothendieck  204.2ms  271.4ms      3.68   33.42MB     9.21
#> 3 fOnyambu        38.6ms   57.5ms     15.2    35.26MB    11.4 
#> 4 fjblood        187.9µs  271.9µs   1972.    390.96KB    11.8

fjblood is orders of magnitude faster and more memory efficient.

Unless the data is large a simple one line solution seems preferable to a complex faster solution involving hard to understand indexing.

The indexing got complicated somewhat due to column b pointing past the end of the data. Other than that, it is pretty straightforward. For simple rolling sums / means, it is better to shift to thinking in terms of differencing a cumsum. The additional logical complexity is no worse than having to remember which function to use from which package and becoming familiar with the function arguments. But it has the clear benefit of computational efficiency. Plus, you don't have to rely on external packages.
